# How do I retrieve the first and last name of a google account that i'm logged in, in Android?

Tags: android, google-authentication

I have a simple application with google authentification, and I want to display a welcome message. If the email account is j**ohnsmith@gmail.com**, I want a `Toast` with **"Welcome John Smith!"** How can I do that?

This is my code:

```
if (user == null) {
        startActivityForResult(AuthUI.getInstance().createSignInIntentBuilder().build(), SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Welcome " + userName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

I tried to use this code, but I get only the user name, not the first and last name.

```
AccountManager manager = (AccountManager) getSystemService(ACCOUNT_SERVICE);
Account[] list = manager.getAccounts();
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**onActivityResult**:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent result) {
    if (requestCode == GOOGLE_REQUEST_CODE) { // Google + callback
       handleSignInResult(Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(result));
       }
}
```

**handleSignInResult** :

```
private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult googleSignInResult) {
    if (googleSignInResult.isSuccess()) {
        GoogleSignInAccount acct = googleSignInResult.getSignInAccount();
        if (acct != null) {
            //get the data you need from GoogleSignInAccount
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

You can find more on `GoogleSignInAccount` :
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInAccount

Comment: I finally made it. This answer helped me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Okay edited answer -

```
Cursor c = activity.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Profile.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
int count = c.getCount();
String[] columnNames = c.getColumnNames();
boolean b = c.moveToFirst();
int position = c.getPosition();
if (count == 1 && position == 0) {
for (int j = 0; j < columnNames.length; j++) {
    String columnName = columnNames[j];
    String columnValue = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(columnName)));
    ...
    //Use the values
    }
}
c.close();
```

j = 0 represents DISPLAY_NAME.

But this is available from ICS onwards only. Add the READ_PROFILE and READ_CONTACTS permission in your AndroidManifest.

Comment: Thanks, but as i already said, i used this code. I get only the user name. I need the the first and the last name.

Comment: He need only first name not entire name with id.

Comment: @AlexM. see the edited answer. And please accept the answer if it helped you in any way. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks you but i get an error: `cannot resolve symbol activity`.

Comment: @AlexM. If you are using this code snippet in MainActivity use `this` instead of `activity`. You just need to replace `activity` with the correct context instance.